# Is there a way to use Shopify API to track placed orders?

Tags: api, shopify

I am trying to set up a Shopify store to just handle the payment stuff (checkout). I seem to be able to do everything I want through the API, so users only go to Shopify for checkout.

I used these instructions to send users directly to the Shopify checkout once they are ready:
http://www.shopify.com/technology/4849802-new-feature-cart-permalinks

On that page it says "tracking parameters can be added", but I can't find any further explanation about that anywhere. My problem is that once users are sent to the checkout page, there is no way to track them as far as I can tell. I have my own user accounts. I would like users to be able to see their orders. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can register to receive [webhook notifications](http://wiki.shopify.com/WebHook) whenever an order is placed. The notification will include the user's info (name, email, shipping and billing addresses) along with details of the items they purchased.

If your users have an email associated with their account you can match that with the one on the order and track it that way.

Answer (score 0):

+1 on using [webhooks](http://wiki.shopify.com/WebHook). If you are using the Ruby version of the API I'd like to suggest that you use [Sinatra](http://rubygems.org/gems/sinatra) to create a simple endpoint for your webhook to talk to. Something like this should get you started:

```
require 'sinatra'

post '/webhooks/orders/create' do
   puts request
   puts request.body.read
end
```

You can run it like so (assuming you save the script to my_sinatra_test.rb):

```
ruby my_sinatra_test.rb
```

And then test it from another terminal with curl:

```
curl -d "foo=1" "http://localhost:4567/webhooks/orders/create"
```

Once you get your head around this go ahead and create a Shopify web hook for Orders/Create and configure it to talk to your sinatra app. Have fun!